# Add a dynamic row inside each row of a table

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a row consisting of 2 dropdowns as two columns, one column with radio and 2 date columns.In each row along with this I need a table in each row which may have multiple rows.

Comment: kindly add code.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far and what would be the expected output